# Difference between @($null) and $null

Tags: .net, powershell

I have some PowerShell code where I am invoking a .NET method which expects a class to be passed as a parameter.

The method accepts a null value as the parameter, and in C# you'd call it as follows:

```
var T = New Foo(null)
```

If translating this into PowerShell, one would try:

```
$T = New-Object Foo($null)
```

But that returns the following error

```
New-Object : Constructor not found. Cannot find an appropriate constructor for type Foo
```

Funilly enough, the exact same error is returned if I call it as:

```
$T = New-Object Foo
```

So first question is why? Does .NET see `$null` as the absence of something, as oppose to the type `null` from .NET? Is that why the two instructions above return the same error?

Now, I found a way around to this problem as follows:

```
$T = New-Object Foo(@($null))
```

This works just fine, but... why?

`(@($Null)).GetType()` returns `object[]`

`(@()).GetType()` also return `object[]`, but if I run:

```
$T = New-Object Foo(@())
```

I still get:

```
New-Object : Constructor not found. Cannot find an appropriate constructor for type Foo
```

So, second question: What is the difference between @(), @($null) and $null?

Also, and last question, this is something else I don't understand.

Let's say I have another .NET method as `Bar(string, Foo)`

If I call:

```
$B = New-Object Bar("s", $null)
```

This works just fine, without having to convert it into an object[] or anything alike.

So the third and last question is: why does the number of parameters affect whether it needs to be passed as an array or not?

My guess would be that if I was to cast it into an array I would call it as

```
$B = New-Object Bar(@("s", $null))
```

Meaning that even though the method expects two parameters, I'm passing it only one as an array of objects and then it automatically maps each of the array items onto the parameters, but that still doesn't quite provide an answer for the first two questions :)

**EDIT**

I know that @() is an empty array and that @($null) is an array with one element which happens to be null, so that's not what I'm asking.

However, if calling:

`$T = New-Object Foo($null)`

Makes Foo's constructor see no parameter as being passed, why does calling `@()` vs calling `@($null)` differ? Surely `@($null)` should be the same as `@()` in this case, the absence of a parameter as it gets seen in the .NET method.

Why does `$null` sometimes mean something and sometimes nothing at all?

Comment: this may answer some of your questions. http://rkeithhill.wordpress.com/2007/09/24/effective-powershell-item-8-output-cardinality-scalars-collections-and-empty-sets-oh-my/

Comment: @andyb, it doesn't. I doesn't even begin to touch on the difference between `$null`, `@()`, `@($null)` or why passing `$null` as a parameter vs passing nothing returns exactly the same result.

Comment: $null is the value null, @() is an empty array, @($null) is an array containing one element which value is null.

Comment: if `$null` was equivalent to `null` then I'd be able to just run `$T = New-Object Foo($null)`, which I can't without an error. There has to be a difference. And seeing as `$null` is not the same as `null` in .NET, why does passing an array with a single element which is null work when passing straight from the bat a single element of `$null` doesn't? Surely `@($null)` should be the same as `$null` when passing it as parameters to a method/function?

Comment: @cogumel0, to paraphrase your own comment: "Surely an array with nothing in it is the same as nothing at all?" It's self-evident that this is not the case, since in the first instance you have an array and in the second you do not. For example, if you pass in `$null` to a method that checks for the length of the array, you'll get an error. It might be that the method you're calling is badly-written, and expects `params[0]` to exist (even if it's null), for example. (That doesn't answer your original question RE the constructor, though.)

Comment: Can you share the code/signature of your .NET method?

Comment: Just look at anything that is nullable. Doesn't matter what. Even a string, as shown here: https://connect.microsoft.com/PowerShell/feedback/details/307821/it-isnt-possible-to-pass-null-as-null-into-a-net-method-that-has-a-parameter-of-type-string. As you can see this was fixed in PowerShell v3 but only for strings, not other types.

Comment: Also see here for another good example of this issue: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/93bddee4-6aee-4641-b104-170968ad1549/automating-application-creation?forum=configmanagersdk#ce9d0e8b-eac4-4453-8101-79990e3e6684

Comment: @DanPuzey You're missing the point when you paraphrase what I said. Obviously an array with a single element of $null is not the same as $null. Let's look at this differently. If we have the following method: `FooBar(string, string)`, I can call it as either... `$T = New-Object FooBar("a", "b")` or as `$T = New-Object FooBar(@("a","b"))`. They both produce the same results yet one passes a two arguments and the other one. There is a single constructor that accepts two arguments, but this works. But calling `New-Object Foo($null)` is NOT the same as `New-Object Foo(@($null))` which it should be

Comment: by 'is not the same as' read 'does not produce the same results as' on the comment above.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Based on your edit, you have a good understanding of the differences between $null and @($null).

Unlike a normal call to a .Net method, calling the constructor requires calling the New-Object cmdlet first.  The syntax for New-Object is:

```
New-Object [-TypeName] <string> [[-ArgumentList] <Object[]>] [-Property <IDictionary>]
```

Let's think for a moment how New-Object works.  Using reflection, New-Object will call TypeName.GetConstructors() and find candidate constructors that can accept n arguments where n is the number of arguments in ArgumentList.

If you call New-Object like this:

```
New-Object -TypeName Foo
```

Then ArgumentList has the value $null.  You didn't pass $null, but that's it's value anyway.  If ArgumentList is $null, there are no arguments.  In this example, that's obvious, you didn't specify -ArgumentList.  If you write:

```
New-Object -TypeName Foo -ArgumentList $null
```

This ends up with the same end result - no argument list.  ArgumentList expects an [object[]], and $null is a perfectly valid value for [object[]], but it means there are no arguments.

If you write:

```
New-Object -TypeName Foo -ArgumentList @($null)
```

Now you are passing an [object[]] with a single value, the value $null, and everything works as you expect.

This is undoubtedly confusing, but it helps to think of how you might implement your own C# function that calls another function and accepts a param array.  If your param array is null, you received no extra arguments.

New-Object can be even more confusing in some cases.  I was personally tripped up by overloaded constructors, one taking an array, the other taking multiple arguments.  In C#, the constructors were something like:

```
Foo(object[] array);   // #1
Foo(string s, int i);  // #2
```

And my incorrect attempt to call constructor #1:

```
New-Object -TypeName Foo -ArgumentList @($array)
```

This calls constructor #2 because New-Object always expects an [object[]] to pass multiple arguments and rarely do you want to call a constructor with a single array argument.  The correct PowerShell would be:

```
New-Object -TypeName Foo -ArgumentList (,$array)
```

Because of this confusion, I added a new way to call constructors in PowerShell V5.  It's available as a very early preview now (http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42936), the syntax looks like a static method call:

```
[Foo]::new($name, $count)
```

With this new syntax, calling constructors is no longer confusing, and as a side benefit, it's also an order of magnitude faster than calling New-Object.

EDIT: I corrected the example with overloaded constructors.

Comment: Great explanation and you fixed something on top. Someone give this man a beer. So currently to be on the safe side one should always place any parameters into an array. That would remove the problem you encountered with your example of overloaded constructors. `New-Object -TypeName Foo -ArgumentList @(@($name, $count))` would call the first constructor and `New-Object -TypeName Foo -ArgumentList @($name, $count)` would call the second constructor. Gets very messy very quickly, that's true, but it sounds like it is the only sure way of getting it to always do what you want, no surprises.

Comment: Counter question: So on the new method of calling constructors in PowerShell v5, would I be able to do: `[Foo]::new($null)` as well?

Comment: Always passing an array can look a little ugly but it does avoid surprises.  And yes, [Foo]::new($null) would pass $null to the constructor taking a single argument like you'd expect, not result in an error.

Comment: I made a correction to my example - adding @() didn't actually have an effect other than to change the syntax.  In fact, @(1,2) and (1,2) are equivalent - @() just ensures you end up with an array, but if you know you have one already, then it's a nop.

Comment: In your corrected example, wouldn't `New-Object -TypeName Foo -ArgumentList @(@($Name, $Count))` or `New-Object -TypeName Foo -ArgumentList @(@($Array))` both call constructor #1 (even though they both look extremely ugly)

Comment: Try it - you'll find that #2 is called assuming $Name is a string and $Count is an int and $Array has 2 values, a string and an int.  Otherwise it will be an error.  Multiple @() doesn't change anything actually, it's the unary comma operator that makes the difference.

Comment: I thought that all the unary comma operator did was wrap the object in an array with a single element, the object itself. If that were the case though then it would be the same as having @($object) right? PS: I only didn't try it because I can't think of any .NET methods multiple constructors that would fit the bill.

Comment: I named the variable $array to suggest it was already an array, not a single element.  You can use Add-Type to experiment, the type I hit this with might have been my own (see https://github.com/lzybkr/TabExpansionPlusPlus/blob/master/TabExpansion%2B%2B.psm1#L1149)